# События в css3 :focus

Tags: css3, focus

Здравствуйте. 
Есть такие поля для ввода текста:

```
<label for="i">Имя</label> <input type="text" id="i"/>
<label for="f">Фамилия</label> <input type="text" id="f"/>
<label for="o">Отчество</label> <input type="text" id="o"/>
```

Нужно задать такой эффект, при фокусе поля, label менял цвет фона.

Посмотрите пожалуйста пример: [Демо](http://dropthebit.com/demos/translationSystem/translate.html)

На странице, куда вы перешли, когда нажимаешь на поле, label меняет цвет фона на красный, как мне добиться такого же эффекта?

Я написал такой код, посмотрите пожалуйста: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4E5bD/)

Мой код работает не правильно, при нажатии на поле, сразу пару label'ов меняют цвет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью css вы этого не добьетесь, т.к. нельзя выбрать элемент, предшествующий выбранному. Вашу задачу надо решать на js, например с помощью jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/4E5bD/1/

Можно попробовать как-то так, если на чистом css, но это не выход http://jsfiddle.net/4E5bD/2/

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я буду больше читать книги)). Благодарю.